# Why we dont consider the complements of other inputs in encoder equations?

Tags: digital-logic, encoder

Consider the below diagram of the 8:3 encoder from this [page](http://www.expertsmind.com/questions/explain-working-of-encoders-30182824.aspx).

[image]

Above,

> n0 = I1 + I3 + I5 + I7
>   n1 = I2 + I3 + I6 + I7
>   n2 = I4 + I5 + I6 + I7

I was guessing why we dont consider complements corresponding to zeroes in the truth table in the image. This will lead to equations something like this:

> n0 = I0'I1 I2'I3'I4'I5'I6'I7' + I0'I1'I2'I3 I4'I5'I6'I7' + I0'I1'I2'I3'I4'I5 I6'I7' + I0'I1'I2'I3'I4'I5'I6'I7

Comment: I guess if you make sure that not more than one bit of input is on, diagram shown in question is enough. But if two input bits are on at a time, then using what's shown in question is not enough. In that case, you need to build what you are suggesting, which is using complements of other bits.

Answer (score 2):

It is assumed that the lower order bits are ignored in this truth table or x= don't care when a higher order bit=1  Therefore the inverse terms are ignored. b7=MSB and b0=LSB (least significant bit)

Yes, this is called a Priority Encoder.

Comment: Isnt that the behavior of "priority" encoder? I guess whenever someone says "encoder", its always assumed that they mean "priority encoder", right?

Comment: (continued from last comment) Found [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_4.html) which says: "One of the main disadvantages of standard digital encoders is that they can generate the wrong output code when there is more than one input present at logic level “1”. For example, if we make inputs D1 and D2 HIGH at logic “1” both at the same time, the resulting output is neither at “01” or at “10” but will be at “11” which is an output binary number that is different to the actual input present."

Comment: It is not actually priority encoder. Say for eg: If \$I_4 = 1\$  \$I_2 = 1\$ and \$I_1 = 1 \$, rest are \$0\$. Then the output would be: '111'. For a priority encoder, it should have been '100'.

Comment: @MituRaj Tony said "It is assumed that the lower order bits are ignored in this truth table or x= don't care when a higher order bit=1", which is priority encoder behavior which will output 100. A non-priority encoder will output 111, right? If yess, I guess truth table and circuit diagram in figure I specified in question dont match as the truth table of priority encoder explicitly shows dont cares as shown [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/combination-comb12.gif), right?

Comment: That's right ...If it were dont cares, it would be priority encoder and the expressions for n0, n1, n2 would actually be different as shown here --> https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_4.html

Comment: one last question. I have came across problems asking to [prepare 16:1 multiplexer by cascading multiple 4:1 multiplexers](http://www.exploreroots.com/dc28.html) and similar problems of forming bigger demultiplexer and decoder using smaller ones by cascading. I also came across problems asking to form larger encoders using smaller encoders, but they always involved priority encoders. For e.g. [this one](https://postimg.cc/5X6SNJ3s/cdcc1fa6) constructs 8:3 priority encoder using 4:2 priority encoders. I want to know if we can prepare such for non priority encoders. I tried but didnt succeed.

Comment: For the OR gates given the Truth Table is wrong and ought to have X to the right of any 1 as a Priority Encoder, whereas your equation accurately reflect the table. But this is Not your fault.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the equivalent circuit/equations for \$n0\$, \$n1\$, \$n2\$ were derived with the assumption that ONLY one input of the 8:3 encoder will be '1' at any given time. Otherwise you are right.